# Gammu-smsd runonreceive returns 0 but no program output

Tags: c++, fork, gammu

I've written a C application that grabs some sensor data and puts it into a string. This string gets passed to gammu-smsd-inject for transmission by SMSD. For reference, my application launches gammu-smsd-inject using fork() & wait(). The program waits for gammu-smsd-inject to terminate and then exits itself.

My program works just fine: if I run it manually from a bash prompt it grabs the sensor data, calls gammu-smsd-inject and quits. The sms appears in the database outbox and shortly after I receive an sms on my phone.

I've added the absolute path to my program into the runonreceive directive of SMSD. When I send a text to SMSD, it is received in the inbox and from the log file I can see the daemon running my program. The logfile then states that the process (my program) successfully exited (0), but I never receive any sms and nothing is added to the database's outbox or sentitems tables.

Any idea what might be going on? I haven't posted a code listing as it's quite long,but it is available.

The only think I could think of that might be happening is that gammu-smsd-inject is perhaps being terminated (by a parent process somewhere up the tree) BEFORE it gets a chance to do any SQL stuff. Wouldn't this create a non zero exit code though?

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to the title. The way to indicate that your problem has been solved is to accept an answer. If you found the answer yourself, it's perfectly ok to post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was which user was running the program. When I ran my application manually from bash, it launch it with my user ID, but when the SMSD daemon ran it, it was launched with a different ID which was causing issues for some reason. I thought it was a problem with the user ID being used to access the mysql database, but apparently not. In short, I don't actually know what the problem was, but by assigning my login's UID to the child process, everything suddenly worked.